# How to call a method via notification within service itself?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code

**FloatingCircle** is the service started by **MainActivity.class**

I want to call method **Visibility()** when i click on **Dismiss** button in notification

```
     public class FloatingCircle extends Service {

        public void onCreate () {
                super.onCreate();
                initializeView();
                getScreenSize();
                showFloat();


                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


                String channelId = "channel-id";
                String channelName = "Channel Name";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                            channelId, channelName, importance);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                }

           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FloatingCircle.class **// What should be here could you suggest me**);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);


                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)//R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                        .setContentTitle("Bubble Life")
                        .setContentText("Touch to On/Off")
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_name,
                                "Dismiss", pIntent)// Here Dismiss is Button shown in notification
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

                notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }
        }

This method must be invoked when Dismiss Button is clicked

            public void Visibility(()
            {
                //some code here
                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(smallCircle);
                Log.d("lol","Done Killing");
            }

 public void killbubble()
    {

        Visibility();
        selfstop();

    }
```

I have tried one thing that i have created another service and invoked Floatingclass method....

```
public class MethodCaller extends Service {

    FloatingCircle floatingCircle=new FloatingCircle();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("lol","yeah");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lol",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        floatingCircle.killbubble();
        stopSelf();
        return flags;
    }

}
```

I have succeed in it but this is giving me an error......

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.WindowManager.removeViewImmediate(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.anam.floatimage.model.FloatingCircle.Visibility(FloatingCircle.java:547)
        at com.anam.floatimage.model.FloatingCircle.killbubble(FloatingCircle.java:777)
        at com.anam.floatimage.MethodCaller.onStartCommand(MethodCaller.java:36)
```

Comment: I prayag, adding sentences like "Please Help it is very important and urgent" actually have a negative connotation on SO. It generally discourages people from answering your question, because well, we all think our own problems are very important and urgent. Just some behavior to avoid in the future!

Comment: For being "very important and urgent", your question doesn't mention much about what you have tried so far -- which would encourage people to help you when it would at least seem that you had actually tried something.